# Randomly change media player volume

Tags: java, android, random, fade, volume

I'm writing an android application with Java in Eclipse.

The media player plays a track when a button is pressed, but I want this track to fade in and out randomly from total silence to full volume and anywhere in between.

I'm thinking of using a random number generator to determine output volume.

Any suggestions of how to do this and example code would be highly appreciated.

When I try this:

```
while (mp.isPlaying()) {
        float x = (float) Math.random();
        float y = (float) Math.random();
        setInterval((mp.setVolume(x,y)),2000);}
```

Eclipse tells me that setInterval is undefined. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function: it will give you a random `int` between `min` and `max`.

```
/** Returns a random int in the specified range. */
static int randomInt(float min, float max) {
    if (max < min) {
        max = min;
    }

    int randInt = (int) (new Random(System.nanoTime()).nextInt((int) (max - min + 1)) + min);
    return randInt;
}
```

You can create a simple loop using a `Handler` to fade the volume in and out as well:

```
void increaseVolume() {
    if (volume < 1) {
        volume += 0.01;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                increaseVolume();
                mp.setVolume(volume);
            }
        }, 100);
    } else {
        volume = 1;
    }
}
```

Remember to also add `float volume = 0` at the start of your activity to store the volume in between adjustments.

Comment: Create a variable in your activity called volume... Then, the code above should work fine to fade in the volume, and just apply the same principle for fading out...

Answer (score 0):

To get random numbers , use :

```
volume = random.nextInt(maxvol - minvol) +minvol;
```

where **maxvol** corresponds to *maximum* volume and **minvol** corresponds to *minimum* volume.

**Note:** You can also use *nextfloat()* instead or with *nextint()* for *extra* precision.